# Postgresql convert query to view with generic month parameter

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a **very big** query.

*In* that query I have to define a date range e.g. where date between x and y.  The defining of the date range is a select query within another select query.

I want this query to be converted to a view.  So that it groups all the results by month e.g. where date between '2000-01-01' and '2000-01-31'.

Is there some sort of way to have it do this, e.g.

```
where date in unique month
```

so that I can make another query that is just

```
select * from temp_view where (max_start_date, max_end_date) overlaps ('2000-01-01', '2000-01-31')
```

Kind of hard to explain...

Would sort of be like inputting all possible months into the query.

This is a sample query

```
    data_table
    fruit  | start_date  |  end_date
    APPLE    2000-01-14     2000-01-20
    APPLE  | 2000-01-20  |  2000-02-05
    ORANGE | 2000-01-01  |  2000-02-10

    value_table (there is a reading every day)
   trading_date | fruit  | value
    2000-01-01   APPLE    1
    2000-01-02   APPLE    1.2
    2000-01-03   APPLE    2.2
    ...
    2000-02-15   APPLE   4.4
    2000-02-16   APPLE   5.2
    ...
    2000-01-01   ORANGE    2
    2000-01-02   ORANGE    3
    2000-01-03   ORANGE    1
    ...
    2000-02-15   ORANGE   2.4
    2000-02-16   ORANGE   2.2
```

The query:

```
    with prequery as (SELECT   value, start_date, end_date
        from data_table
            )     
            SELECT 
                month,
                some_value,
                start_date,
                end_date,
                sum(daily_value)
                FROM  prequery
                INNER JOIN value_table
                on fruit=value_table.fruit  
                and trading_date between start_date and  end_date
                ->[[[and trading_date between '2000-01-01' and '2000-01-31']]]<- dont want this.  Want it to group by months.
```

Output  (does not include all values but just to show what I am aiming for)

```
Month  |  value  |  start_date   | end_date   | sum   |    
2000-01   APPLE     2000-01-20    2000-02-05    (sum of all values between start and end dates in January for APPLE)
2000-02   APPLE     2000-01-14    2000-01-20    (sum of all values between start and end dates in February for APPLE)
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Hi Gordon,  I have added some sample data to clarify the question.  Daryn

Answer (score 0):

Are you searching for a view from which you can select the first and the last day for a month?

This one will create a view `months` with all months from January 1970 to December 2070.

```
CREATE VIEW months
AS
WITH RECURSIVE cte(i, number_of_year, number_of_month, first_day, last_day)
AS
(
SELECT 1 i,
       0 / 12 + 1970 number_of_year,
       0 % 12 + 1 number_of_month,
       (lpad((0 / 12 + 1970)::text, 4, '0') || '-' || lpad((0 % 12 + 1)::text, 2, '0') || '-01')::timestamp first_day,
       (lpad((0 / 12 + 1970)::text, 4, '0') || '-' || lpad((0 % 12 + 1)::text, 2, '0') || '-01')::timestamp + INTERVAL '1 month - 1 day' last_day
UNION ALL
SELECT i + 1 i,
       i / 12 + 1970 number_of_year,
       i % 12 + 1 number_of_month,
       (lpad((i / 12 + 1970)::text, 4, '0') || '-' || lpad((i % 12 + 1)::text, 2, '0') || '-01')::timestamp first_day,
       (lpad((i / 12 + 1970)::text, 4, '0') || '-' || lpad((i % 12 + 1)::text, 2, '0') || '-01')::timestamp + INTERVAL '1 month - 1 day' last_day
       FROM cte
       WHERE i / 12 + 1970 <= 2070
)
SELECT number_of_year,
       number_of_month,
       first_day,
       last_day
       FROM cte;
```

But I recommend materializing this for better performance.

```
CREATE TABLE months
AS
WITH RECURSIVE cte(i, number_of_year, number_of_month, first_day, last_day)
AS
(
SELECT 1 i,
       0 / 12 + 1970 number_of_year,
       0 % 12 + 1 number_of_month,
       (lpad((0 / 12 + 1970)::text, 4, '0') || '-' || lpad((0 % 12 + 1)::text, 2, '0') || '-01')::timestamp first_day,
       (lpad((0 / 12 + 1970)::text, 4, '0') || '-' || lpad((0 % 12 + 1)::text, 2, '0') || '-01')::timestamp + INTERVAL '1 month - 1 day' last_day
UNION ALL
SELECT i + 1 i,
       i / 12 + 1970 number_of_year,
       i % 12 + 1 number_of_month,
       (lpad((i / 12 + 1970)::text, 4, '0') || '-' || lpad((i % 12 + 1)::text, 2, '0') || '-01')::timestamp first_day,
       (lpad((i / 12 + 1970)::text, 4, '0') || '-' || lpad((i % 12 + 1)::text, 2, '0') || '-01')::timestamp + INTERVAL '1 month - 1 day' last_day
       FROM cte
       WHERE i / 12 + 1970 <= 2070
)
SELECT number_of_year,
       number_of_month,
       first_day,
       last_day
       FROM cte;
```

I imagine you will query it like that:

```
SELECT first_day,
       last_day
       FROM months
       WHERE number_of_year = <year>
             AND number_of_month = <month>;
```

Then also create the following index to support it.

```
CREATE INDEX months_number_of_year_number_of_month_first_day_last_day
             ON months (number_of_year,
                        number_of_month,
                        first_day,
                        last_day);
```